# What is the correct way to pass an object as prop in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to pass an object of image URL's as a prop to a child component and use it in the src attribute of an image component. However I keep getting an error saying that my object key (image1,2 or 3) is undefined. I tried it without destructuring and the same thing happens. What am I doing wrong?

**Object with urls**

```
const imgUrls = {
        image1: '/images/exodevo.webp',
        image2: '/images/njordic.webp',
        image3: '/images/geotechniek.webp',
    }
```

**Parent component (ProjectSection.js)**

```
  <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4 px-0" data-aos="flip-left">
     <ProjectPreview title={"ExoDevo"} content={"This was a website I built for ExoDevo during my internship at NC-Websites."} techs={"HTML/CSS/JS"} images={{...imgUrls}} website={"https://www.exodevo.com"} />
  </div>
```

**Image component in child component ProjectPreview.js**

```
  <Image
    src={props.images}
    alt={props.title}
    width={335}
    height={210}
  />
```

Comment: Please add some more context: How are you using the Image component on the ProjectView?

Comment: `Object.keys(props.images).map(k => <Image  src={props.images[k]}/>)`

Comment: You named the object imgUrls, but called props.images, is this correct? Could you show more code about the Image component?

Comment: @Mastermind I already found my mistake. I tried to add a prop images and insert the destructured object where i should have just done {...imgUrls} directly. So not images={{...imgUrls}}

Comment: Do not use {} when passing strings down to a child component. Pass the string directly as you would write an HTML attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to pass an array of images into the `<ProjectPreview />`component. Then, iterate throught it to display `<Image />` component.

ProjectSection.js:

```
const images = Object.values(imgUrls);

return (
  <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4 px-0" data-aos="flip-left">
     <ProjectPreview title="ExoDevo" content="This was a website I built for ExoDevo during my internship at NC-Websites." techs="HTML/CSS/JS" images={images} website="https://www.exodevo.com" />
  </div>
);
```

ProjectPreview.js:

```
return (
   <>
     {/* Other stuff */}
     {props.images.map((src) => (
        <Image src={src} />
     ))}
   </>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I already found out what I was doing wrong. Instead of this:

```
  <ProjectPreview title={"ExoDevo"} content={"This was a website I built for ExoDevo during my internship at NC-Websites."} techs={"HTML/CSS/JS"} images={{...imgUrls}} website={"https://www.exodevo.com"} />
```

I should have just done this:

```
 <ProjectPreview title={"ExoDevo"} content={"This was a website I built for ExoDevo during my internship at NC-Websites."} techs={"HTML/CSS/JS"} {...imgUrls} website={"https://www.exodevo.com"} />
```

Comment: Remove the `...`